# Niveau von "so gut (wie) du kannst"

Tags: usage

> (a) Tu so gut wie du kannst.
>
> (b) Tu so gut du kannst.

Sind beide Sätze grammatikalisch korrekt? Wie klingt (b), verglichen mit (a)? Ist es formeller oder informeller, und würde man es im Alltagsgespräch verwenden?

Comment: Generell ist est nie wirklich gut, das Wort "tun" zu verwenden. In diesem Fall würde ich sagen: "Mach es so gut du kannst.", oder einfach: "Gib dein Bestes"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dass die beiden Beispielsätze auf einem stilistisch niedrigen Niveau angesiedelt werden, hat weniger mit den Teil "so gut (wie) du kannst" zu tun, sondern mit dem *Tu* am Beginn des Satzes.

Ich ersetze daher das Verb durch ein konkreteres:

> (a) Tanze so gut, wie du kannst.
>   (b) Tanze so gut du kannst.

Diese beiden Sätze sind beide grammatisch korrekt und beide stilistisch hochwertiger als die jeweiligen ursprünglichen Beispiele.

Von diesen beiden Varianten ist jedoch eindeutig der ohne "wie" der Vorzug zu geben:

> Tanze so gut du kannst.
>   Bau das Haus so gut du kannst.
>   Spiele so gut du kannst auf der Geige.

Comment: Beispiel a) mit Komma geht nur mit "es" als Platzhalter im Nebensatz: "Tanze so gut, wie du es kannst". b) und die drei unteren Beispiele benötigen alle ein Komma: Tanze, so gut du kannst / Bau das Haus, so gut du kannst / Spiele, so gut du kannst, auf der Geige.

Answer (score 2):

Ich würde weder a) noch b) benutzen, weil sie grammatikalisch nicht korrekt klingen. "Gib Dein Bestes" oder "Mache es so gut wie Du kannst" wäre angebrachter.

Comment: Ja, das *tu* ohne Objekt könnte regional sein.

Answer (score 1):

Ich habe immer 'so gut du nur kannst' gehört, was unterstreicht, dass man sich richtig anstrengen muss.